error executing "abp login username": Failed to load /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.5/libhostfxr.so
when I run "abp login " I get the error below.
Failed to load /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.5/libhostfxr.so, error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.5/libhostfxr.so)
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.5/libhostfxr.so failed

Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370

It is strange because i've installed sdk and runtime via package manager apt (Ubuntu 22.04) and the prerequisites should have been installed  together.

Did you solve this error? I'm getting the same error at Ubuntu 24
